# Rendering Sonata Admin Twig Files Variable Form Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata

I'm working on a custom controller/function in symphony2/sonata admin panel. I want to render the file using:

```
return $this->render('SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
```

I get the error

```
Variable "form" does not exist in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig
```

Hers the line in the twig:

```
<td class="filter-type">{{ form_widget(form.getChild(filter.formName).getChild('type')) }}</td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you know that you need to pass the form to the view.
So I guess you haven't the form.

You need to work in the controller of the corresponding admin class (sonata) to render the `Datagrid` form. Otherwise, you need to rewrite the whole logic.

That includes all the form building/processing using (or not) the DatagridMapper.

You should keep in mind that forms and lists represent the main components of sonata-admin (same for every admin panel), and although they are based on symfony forms, it represent a fully customised behavior.

So, for use sonata, you need to be in a sonata context.
(In this case, of one of their CRUD actions)

Answer (score 1):

You also have to pass the form view to render.

```
return $this->render('SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities, 'form' => $form->createView()));
```